# In Java, how to apply interest on certain amount of the total amount

Tags: java, math, if-statement, rate

I have a problem to solve in Java. Basically, I have to calculate how many KWH customer has had spent last month till today. From 0-300 KWH it is $5 total. From 301 to 1000kwh it is $5 for first 300kwh and then each kwh is $0.03 extra. from 1001 and above it is $0.02 extra for each kwh. I am not sure how to apply those 0.03 and 0.02 on each kwh after 300kwh. Thanks.

Comment: How would you do it without a computer? Use a pencil and paper, and write down the steps you would use...

Comment: Homework assignment? If so, this is one of the stranger ones.

Comment: It is a homework. I tried on paper too, i got to some point, but then when i want to use IF-statement in Java i get stuck when I have to apply that interest after 300kwh.

Comment: no loops just IF statement, no switch.

Comment: If it is homework, you should still show the research/effort that you have done and where you are stuck and write it in your question. This is not a write-my-code-for-me website; questions should be useful not just for the poster but for other people who read your question as well.

Comment: I understand what you are saying Erwin. I did not write many lines of program and then got stuck, everything before my question is basic Java. Did not want anyone to write full program for this homework, it would not be right, just wanted to understand the concept of the portion of the problem. I am sure there are people who will find answers useful for their research. I will keep in mind your argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $5.  This is the amount.

```
If the total is greater than 300 kwh,
  then the amount should be increased by $0.03 per kwh above 300.

If the total is greater than 1000 kwh,
  then the amount should be reduced by $0.01 per kwh above 1000.
```

Start with that pseudo-code.  Here's some actual code based on your comments:

```
int totalReading = ...;  // something

// $5 is the minimum cost
double cost = 5.0;

// above 300, the cost is 0.03 per
if (totalReading > 300)
  cost += (totalReading - 300) * 0.03;

// above 1000, the cost drops 0.01 per
if (totalReading > 1000)
  cost -= (totalReading - 1000) * 0.01;
```

Comment: interesting. For example

Comment: If(totalReading>300)  totalReading=oldReading*0.03 ?

Comment: `1000-totalReading` is negative when `totalReading > 1000`.  So it would be good to add that * 0.01 - but this is the same as subtracting `totalReading-1000`.

Comment: Right. I will type the program again. Thanks for your help Erick. Unfortunatelly, can't finish homework tonight, but next thing in the morning.